# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/Lampp/Xampp: An error occurred while extracting files

Tags: xampp, drupal

New to Linux/Ubuntu, XAMPP and Drupal.

I'm trying to install XAMPP/LAMPP/Drupal to a USB thumbdrive and I keep getting: "An error occurred while extracting files".

I have NO idea on how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

fyi: I just removed Microsoft XP and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS about 7 days ago.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install? What commands did you run?

Comment: Hello Eric: I downloaded XAMPP/LAMPP from sourceforge>developement>XAMPP. After it downloads, I try to unzip from the Archive Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your file got corrupted during download. You can check the file integrity by verifying the downloaded file's SHA1 (or MD5) hash.

Go to the XAMPP [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.1/), click the information icon at the right of "xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz" (or any other file you downloaded) and copy the SHA1 (or MD5) hash. Download the file and run in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
cd Download     # <-- The directory where you saved the file.
sha1sum xampp-linux-1.8.1.tar.gz     # <-- The file you downloaded. Replace sha1sum with md5sum if checking MD5 hashes.
```

Check if the hash matches the one copied from the download page.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will try your suggestion later in the day.

Comment: Anyone's input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Terminal: What command(s) do I use to un tar.gz in (to) a USB flash drive? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Eric: I had to download XAMPP again because I couldn't find it in "Download". I had the same error as before. I had to research on how to do the MD5 check (learned here: http://youtu.be/0ExP6RrkzKg). For some reason the file couldn't be found in "Download" but I found it in "TMP". I moved the XAMPP file to "Desktop" and did the MD5 check (e7092eafff81ad363de45d192774b4d6).

I couldn't understand how to follow your 1st instructions by going to the "download page" and clicking to the right of the "information icon". ;(

1 thing I did notice though was that the file in the "Download" has no lock on it while on the "Desktop" it does.

Thanks again for your help.